# Strong polynomial algorithm for linear programming

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming

What is the current state of finding a strong polynomial algorithm for linear programming? Is there any reference?

Comment: IIRC, nothing was really improved after Eva Tardos' work in 1986: http://www.jstor.org/stable/170819

Answer (score 4):

The best known general result is due to Eva Tardos' ["A Strongly Polynomial Algorithm to Solve Combinatorial Linear Programs"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/170819), published in 1986.

Basically, it says that only bitsizes of coefficients in the constraints matrix $A$ need to be taken into account, whereas sizes of coefficients in the RHS $b$ and in the objective function $c$ don't matter, for the LP in the usual form 
$$\max_x \langle c,x\rangle \quad \text{subject to }Ax\leq b.$$